# Why "failed to open stream" error?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I am integrating [Zaincash](https://www.zaincash.iq/en/) module in magento. I am using this [git](https://github.com/vinaysikarwar/zaincash-magento-module). Module is installed and coming in `admin->system->configuration->advanced` but when accessing `payment methods` in admin its throwing `HTTP ERROR 500`.

When I looked into `system.log` file it has following errors:

> 2017-07-10T05:09:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Zcash/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/mysite/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> 2017-07-10T05:09:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Zcash/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/mysite/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
>
> 2017-07-10T05:09:45+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Zcash/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/mysite/app/code/local:/var/www/mysite/app/code/community:/var/www/mysite/app/code/core:/var/wwwmysite/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')  in /var/www/mysite/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Module was installed in `app/code/local/WTC/Zcash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open file

```
app/code/local/WTC/Zcash/etc/system.xml
```

Line No : 27 , replace `module="Zcash"` with below

```
module="zcash"
```

comment below code, line no : 79 to 87

```
<!--<mode translate="label">
                            <label>Transaction Mode</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_mode</source_model>
                            <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </mode>-->
```

Comment: great. Now its showing. But now when placing order getting following error: `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /var/www/mysite/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4039`. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: can you check the exception.log and activate the debug mode if it is not yet activated and check for errors

Comment: There is nothing in `exception.log`