# 500 Internal server error on payment redirect after placing order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, payment-methods

This is a follow-up question to the [Why “failed to open stream” error?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182818/why-failed-to-open-stream-error). I am integrating [Zaincash](https://www.zaincash.iq/en/) module in magento. I am using this extension from [git](https://github.com/vinaysikarwar/zaincash-magento-module). Now when I am clicking on `Place Order` button on magento's default onepage checkout page, page is redirected to `zcash/standard/redirect/` and getting `500 Internal server error`.

When I debugged, I found following code in `app/code/local/WTC/Zcash/Model/Standard.php`:

```
public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()
{
    return Mage::getUrl('zcash/standard/redirect');
}
```

And in `app/code/local/WTC/Zcash/controllers/StandardController.php` action following code:

```
public function redirectAction()
{

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $session->setHdfcStandardQuoteId($session->getQuoteId());
    $order = $this->getOrder();


    if (!$order->getId()) {

        $this->_forward('failurerefresh');
        return;
    }

    $order->addStatusToHistory(
        $order->getStatus(),
        Mage::helper('hdfc')->__('Customer was redirected to hdfc')
    );
    $order->save();

    $this->getResponse()
        ->setBody($this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('hdfc/standard_redirect')
            ->setOrder($order)
            ->toHtml());

    $session->unsQuoteId();
}
```

I think, its controller is faulty. I didn't get what is `hdfc` here? Can anyone help me please?

Comment: can you see your order in admin backend after place an order ?

Comment: @Dhaval yes orders are shown in admin.

Comment: can try to install this module
`https://github.com/vinaysikarwar/HDFC-Payment-Gateway-magento-Extension` because some configuration is come in zcash module from this link module

Answer (score 0):

install below module for current module support
https://github.com/vinaysikarwar/HDFC-Payment-Gateway-magento-Extension

Comment: Its redirecting to homepage.

Comment: what you getting in exception.log?

Comment: you can seen HDFC payemnt method in system -> configuration - paymetn method 
can you fill up all details in this area
and replace line no 363 with below line app/code/local/WTC/Zcash/controllers/StandardController.php
` ->createBlock('zcash/standard_redirect')`

Comment: you just need to add zcash details in hdfc field

Comment: what is used in Payment Gateway Url field ?

Comment: left it blank .

Comment: NO @TriyugiNarayanMani,  Please add 
`https://api.zaincash.iq/transaction/init`

Comment: Now its redirected to `index.php/zcash/standard/redirect/` with blank page. system.log contains following error: `Notice: Undefined offset: 1  in /var/www/mysite/app/code/local/WTC/Zcash/Block/Standard/Redirect.php on line 48`.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani, Hope it will help you . otherwise you need to debug it deeply :)

Comment: Sure. I will debug it now. Thanks for your help.:)